# Is there a planar graph $G+H$, where $G+H$ is the graph join, such that $G$ has 3 vertices and $H$ has 5 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

And how would you solve a problem like this in general? I drew it out and believe the answer is no, but I'm unsure how to prove it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $G+H$? The graph join? Depending on what you mean, well, Euler's formula is always a good place to start (i.e. you may end up with too many edges).

Comment: @Hendrix Yes, I meant the graph join. I have updated the question. Any further help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski's_and_Wagner's_theorems) says the graph is non planar iff there is a copy of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ in it. $G+H$ has a $K_{3,3}$ ..